# Reading in GeoTIFF with different CRS and Transform with rasterio

Tags: python, geotiff-tiff, rasterio, masking, resampling

I have multiple TIF files with different resolutions that I want to combine using rasterio. I am using a modification of the example given in the documentation [here](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/resampling.html). However, on closer inspection whilst all the TIFs have the same CRS, they don't have the same affine transformations.

**OPTION 1** Here is the code I have now:

```
    import rasterio as rio
    import numpy as np
    import numpy.ma as ma

    def tif_load(tif_path, dimensions, resampling_method='bilinear'):
        with rio.open(tif_path) as raster:
        # resample data to target shape
        data = raster.read(1, masked=True, out_shape=(dimensions[0], dimensions[1]),
                           resampling=Resampling[resampling_method]
                           )
        meta = raster.profile
        # scale image transform
        transform = raster.transform * raster.transform.scale(
            (raster.width / data.shape[-1]),
            (raster.height / data.shape[-2])
        )
       return data, meta, transform
```

I guess I could use the code above, but is there anyway to read in the tif file with a particular crs and transform? I was thinking I could use one of my TIFs to set a standard crs and transform and then use the above, passing in this standard crs and transform to read in the others? I would probably have to be careful to remember to modify the meta for the raster to make sure it reflects the destination crs and transform.

**OPTION 2** Alternatively, I could read in the tif files like so

```
import rasterio as rio
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma

with rio.open(tif_path) as raster:
   # resample data to target shape
   data = raster.read(1, masked=True)
   meta = raster.profile
```

And then I could set a standard crs and transform from one of my tifs and use reproject like [they do in the documentation here](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reproject.html). For example, say I set the tif_path as our standard crs and transform and I read in tif_path2 (source) with data2 and meta2, then we can do the following

```
src_transform=meta2['transform']
src_crs=meta2['crs']
source=data2
destination=ma.copy(data)
dst_transform=meta['transform']
dst_crs=meta['crs']
with rio.Env():
    reproject(
    source,
    destination,
    src_transform=src_transform,
    src_crs=src_crs,
    dst_transform=dst_transform,
    dst_crs=dst_crs,
    resampling=Resampling.bilinear)

# Assert that the destination is only partly filled.
assert destination.any()
assert not destination.all()
```

Will these give the same result? Which is better? If this changes things I am reading in the data as a masked array.